# How to set config changes only for one linear/relative layout?

Tags: android, keyboard

In my layout xml file I have webview and LinearLayout.
when I open softinputmethod for webview, webview editText window(like google), is up to keyboard and that is good.
But when keyboard is open, my linearLayout is so squeeze, that all button looks terrifying.

How to set, that keyboard can change webview, but it can't destroy RelativeLayout?

there is some code:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/homebar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         >
...//there is some buttons

</RelativeLayout>
     <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/homebar" />
```

[sorry for my bad english]

Comment: Could you share your layout/code ? also a screenshot with the textView expanded if you can.

Comment: post your output when appearing softkeyboard and you faced struggle

Comment: Please post proper code of your layout & screenshot of the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout is not a good way to handle the views when dynamic View is expected to get loaded in activity afterwards. Do use relative layout to solve this problem out.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was use Relative too, but nothing changes.